# IF statements with a common ELSE clause

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

I come across this problem quite a bit when I'm programming, where I need to use multiple if statements with a common else clause that triggers if none of the if statements trigger. There are a few ways I usually implement this behaviour:

#### Method 1 - Boolean Variable

```py
triggered = False

if condition_1:
    // do stuff
    triggered = True

if condition_2:
    // do some different stuff
    triggered = True

if not triggered:
    // do the default stuff
```

#### Method 2 - Double Checking

```py
if condition_1:
    // do stuff

if condition_2:
    // do some different stuff

if not (condition_1 || condition_2):
    // do the default stuff
```

#### Method 3 - Nested If Statements

```py
if condition_1:
    // do stuff
    if condition_2:
        // do some different stuff
else if condition_2:
    //do some different stuff
else:
    // do the default stuff
```

All three methods are not ideal:
**Method 1:** requires an extra variable and some extra lines
**Method 2:** inefficient since you have to compute the conditions multiple times
**Method 3:** code is repetitive, and will get much more repetitive with more than two if statements

Is there a more concise/cleaner way to implement this behaviour (I'm more concerned about a general solution but if there are language specific solutions for python/java/c++ that would be neat as well)?

Comment: @PioKozi Yes, because that would trigger the else statement anytime the second if condition is False, I want the else statement to trigger if BOTH if statements are False

Comment: No need to design a spaceship. Go with method 1 which is the clearest

Comment: I see nothing wrong with Method 1. Typing is cheap, so you should not care about some extra lines. The extra variable is more of a concern but it has a definite purpose. That code seems clear and modifiable. It also follows structure programming recommendations.

Comment: are conditions are related (best case: exclusive)?

Comment: There's only 3 conditions which are not worth bothering. If you would have had, say 5 dependent conditions with nested conditions - that would be another deal

Answer (score 1):

All three approaches are valid, this all depends on the complexity of code you put in each "stuff".

If these stuffs are short one-line code, I would prefer the approach 3, which does not require any extra variable and will has some performance benefit (it may seem complex to read but not for short code).

If the stuffs are long, adding a control variable will usually not have significant performance cost and will allow easier maintenance (provided you name that control variable clearly, "triggered" may not be specific enough to carry the intended meaning).

Solution 2 works well in medium complexity case but has the small cost of repeated tests of the same conditions: you can save most of that cost by first evaluating the conditions in local boolean control variables (correctly named for clarity), or a single integer variable enumerating the cases (3 values here, just requires 2 bits, 1 per condition) so that the default test will be a simple comparison with 0.

The alternatives are also:
  - to use a `switch()` or `for()` loop, and then "play" with "break", fallthrough, "continue" (in loops) or "goto" labels (placed appropriately depending on cases tuned by profiling for the most frequent cases where you can avoid goto's for the most frequent case),
  - using a private method/local function returning a false boolean saying if a specif action was taken or returning true if the default stuff must be executed (this approach is frequently used for processing events/messages with handlers in message processing loops for UI or network services).

Choose what fits best your project and allows you simplified maintenance. Code clarity is also frequently depending in current organizational standards/conventions: talk with your team to see what they are more cumfortable with, don't assume that code style proposed in various tools suit all needs, but if your development will be open-sourced, prefer using the most common standards followed by larger communities.

If you deviate from it, explain the reasons with comments, for example when you needed it for performance and the code was highly tested and will unlikely change its documented and stabilized/standardized functionality, for which local optimizations may give some advantage, but beware that modern compilers can frequently make better checks and may behave better on other systems than your manual optimization tweaks tested on a more limited number of situations than those that compilers have taken into account, such as different CPUs, parallelization or smaller devices with more limited RAM or caches).

Tweaking optimizations for specific systems is still possible but the quirk is to manage the configurations and detect them properly (and such quirk frequently requires providing alternate code, which increases the maintenance cost) and such optimizations may turn invalid in later generations of processors, OSes, and compilers which are tuned (and sometimes secured better and more easily) for the most common programming patterns and more easily adaptable to new situations and better compatility with future evolutions of existing standards: write your code to allow someone else to reuse it and understand/maintain it in 10 years and when the working teams will have changed (be aware of apparition of new practices, trends, and fast development tool, including code generators and the growing effect of virtualization and deployment/scaling strategies).

The minor optimization made today will soon become insignificant later and will rapidly no longer give advantage compared to the cost of maintenance. In summary, just choose what seems the simplest to understand on first read by someone else that has never seen your code and does not know you. you don't need to provide lot of comments if you program clearly and avoid "spaghetti" code and lot of abbrevs (avoid short variable names like "i" except in very short local scopes, never use them in structures and exported interfaces: such practice is just obfuscation, not causing problems to bots, but complicating the task of human programmers, increasing their workload and programmers often have tool long TODO lists, they don't have a lot of time and hate having to maintain old legacy shaghetti code for features still highly needed because of many other dependencies, and they fear breaking it after trying to work on it for hours, until all their attempted changes are finally reverted and another similar feature is developed and later maintained separately in parallel, adding also to later maintenance costs).

Answer (score -1):

Put the  `elif` statement to use here.
Try `if` - `elif` - `else`:

```
if condition_1:
    #do stuff
    return stuff

elif condition_2:
    #do stuff2
    return stuff_2

elif condition_3:
    #do stuff3
    return stuff_3

else:
    #return default_stuff
```

You could chain if statements together as well:

```
if condition_1a and condition_1b:
    ...
    return x

elif condition2a and condition_2b:
    ...
    return y
else:
    ...
    #return z
```

I'll recommend you read more on Python Condition statements.

Comment: I don't think you understand my question. Each condition HAS to be checked. If condition_1 is true, I still want condition_2 to be checked and run.

Comment: "elif" is not needed after a return. But it makes clear that the intent of the programmer was that the conditions were exclusive (not necessarily true when the "if/elif" are ordered): an "elif" assumes that the tests could be reordered differently (if this is not the case, use "if")

Comment: However, if/elif constructs for exclusive conditions are often rewritable using a switch instead: it is often clearer to first evaluate the exclusive conditions in a simple temporary numeric variable, and then switch on that value (properly chosen: by range if possible, or bitmasks). Conditions are frequently be the most complex part that should be evaluated once.